# rgl install failure in Rstudio on mac

Tags: r, rgl

rgl installed
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load(rgl) : Failed to install/load:
rgl

Answer (score 0):

You don't really post a question (hence the negative scores others have given you), but it appears that the error message is telling you that `rgl` is failing to load because `libGLU.1.dylib` is not found.

You can probably fix this by installing XQuartz, since it looks like you're on a Mac.  Go to https://www.xquartz.org to get it.